# Installing Qualcomm Package Manager on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package, qualcomm

Qualcomm distributes software through its developer network: developer.qualcomm.com.
More recent software requires the use of a dedicated package manager (QPM, the Qualcomm Package Manager).
The QPM available from developer.qualcomm.com for Linux (version 2) as a .deb package is not installable on Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried installing QPM 2 and it missed a dependency (gnome-keyring0) that is apparently not installable on Ubuntu 22.04. Hence I removed the QPM 2 package.

Answer (score -1):

Qualcomm Package Manager version 3 is required for Ubuntu 22.04.
I could download it from its own page:
https://qpm.qualcomm.com/#/main/tools/details/QPM3